# Drupal problems with noConflict JQuery

Tags: javascript, drupal, jquery

Hi I am trying to make a jquery no conflict work as descriped here:
http://drupal.org/node/1058168
I have this in my php template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

I modified my javascript accordingly. But it does not work... it starts the first function, but then after it, it does not run any of it:

```
$jq(function () {
    console.info('First $JQ function');
    //"use strict";
    // this function is strict...
    $jq(document).ready(function () {
```

The `$jq(document).ready(function ()` does not run, hence the whole script stops. The full script is located at www.htconsulting.hu/sites/validation.js

Thank you for your help!

**Update:**: removing the first $jq(function () did help to at least remove the dougle ready functions. Still it does not solve the problem I faced initially for which I use the noConflict. Part of the code would ensure that based on input thhe input area color changes, as the helper text next to it. The text still does not change. Since in my testing enviroment everything worked, I assumed its because the site I am forced to use, uses old Jquery. Appereantly, using the newer one still does not solve the problem. Form located at www.htconsulting/test/form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$jq(function () {
```

is equivalent to

```
$jq(document).ready(function () {
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

So basically you have a `document.ready` inside of a `document.ready`.  I don't think that works, try removing the inner `ready` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that makes the script partially work, and does not solve the problem I wanted to solve by using noConflict. Under the validation, nothing that involves $('').text class works. The text should change based on input. I thought its because the site has different JQuery since the same code works in my testing enviroment. Any ideas on that? + My popup window still does not work

Comment: Using `noConflict` specifically makes it so `$("")` won't work.  You need to use `$jq` anywhere that `$` would have been used.

Comment: That sounds like a different question which requires more information.  Perhaps you should post another question and include the html and js in question.

Comment: Ok I will do that, not familiar with stackoverflow, how so I "close" this question?

Comment: You click the checkmark next to the answer which was most helpful/correct.  That will accept the answer.